# structure of argument php function & php function:object oriented or not?

Tags: php, function

Why some programmer set null in function arguments ?

like:

```
function  func ($arg1, arg2 = null)
{
   print $arg1.' '.$arg2;
}
```

So I can call it with this: `func('test1')`  (without wrote `$arg2`) it print `test1` but if call `func('test1','test2')`... it only print `test1`.

Also speed of run and debug function is very important for me...also all functions are static...I must bring function under a class or without class is more fast? I am not care about object oriented ...only speed.

Comment: You should run your test again, the `func('test1','test2');` should return `test1 test2`. The `= null` sets the default value only.

Comment: The second parameter is missing a `$` sign, which may be why it does not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice trick to emulate variables/function calls/etc as default values:

```
<?php
$myVar = "Using a variable as a default value!";

function myFunction($myArgument=null) {
    if($myArgument===null)
        $myArgument = $GLOBALS["myVar"];
    echo $myArgument;
}

// Outputs "Hello World!":
myFunction("Hello World!");
// Outputs "Using a variable as a default value!":
myFunction();
// Outputs the same again:
myFunction(null);
// Outputs "Changing the variable affects the function!":
$myVar = "Changing the variable affects the function!";
myFunction();
?>
```

In general, you define the default value as null (or whatever constant you like), and then check for that value at the start of the function, computing the actual default if needed, before using the argument for actual work.

Building upon this, it's also easy to provide fallback behaviors when the argument given is not valid: simply put a default that is known to be invalid in the prototype, and then check for general validity instead of a specific value: if the argument is not valid (either not given, so the default is used, or an invalid value was given), the function computes a (valid) default to use.

**Incorrect usage of default function arguments**

```
<?php
function makeyogurt($type = "acidophilus", $flavour)
{
    return "Making a bowl of $type $flavour.\n";
}

echo makeyogurt("raspberry");   // won't work as expected
?>
```

**The above example will output:**

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 in call to makeyogurt() in 
/usr/local/etc/httpd/htdocs/phptest/functest.html on line 41
Making a bowl of raspberry .
```

Now, compare the above with this:

**Correct usage of default function arguments**

```
<?php
function makeyogurt($flavour, $type = "acidophilus")
{
    return "Making a bowl of $type $flavour.\n";
}

echo makeyogurt("raspberry");   // works as expected
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Making a bowl of acidophilus raspberry.
```

**Note:** As of PHP 5, arguments that are passed by reference may have a default value.

Here are few links I am adding for you to learn function arguments in depth -

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php